# Finding class and adding removing class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with following format.

```
<% (1..3).each do %>
<div class="each-message-content notification-message-content">
 <div class="">
  <div class="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="">
 </div>
 <div class="">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="">
</div>
<div class="read-unread">
</div>
<% end %>
```

Clicking on read-unread I add a class read or unread. But when I check for if the class has read or unread class it always execute if block. Never enter in else block. How can I do this?

```
 $(document).on('click','.read-unread', function(){
        var $read_unread = $(this).closest('.notification-message-content');
        if($read_unread.hasClass('unread')){
            $read_unread.removeClass('unread');
            $read_unread.addClass('read');                
        } else if (($read_unread.hasClass('read'))){
            $read_unread.removeClass('read');
            $read_unread.addClass('unread');

        }

    });
```

Comment: See .toggleClass() (or toggleClassName(), not sure).

Answer (score 1):

Going with a definite selector might be even better

```
$(document).on('click','.read-unread', function(){
    $(this).prev().prev().toggleClass('read unread');   ;
});
```

Do note that one of the 'read' / 'unread' class needs to be already in place.

Comment: +1 even seems more portable: `$(this).siblings('.notification-message-content').toggleClass('read unread');`

Comment: I think the problem is I am using a loop here. So same class appear 3 times. Thats why none of the answers are working for me. I think we have to find closest class name notification-message-content

Comment: @user3128796 If the structure is the same as you mentioned. My answer should work, as it does not depend on the css class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.read-unread', function () {
    var $read_unread = $(this).prevAll('.notification-message-content').first();
    $read_unread.toggleClass('unread read');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh5nD/4/)

Comment: @Satpal: Added toggleClass() solution also. Thanks Bro. :)

Comment: I think the problem is I am using a loop here. So same class appear 3 times. Thats why none of the answers are working for me. I think we have to find closest class name notification-message-content

Comment: @user3128796: Please find updated answer with demo link.

Answer (score 0):

`.closest()` looks up the DOM tree. `.notification-message-content` is not up the tree, it is on the same level as `.read-unread`. Since we know it's above it, you can write

```
var $read_unread = $(this).prevAll('.notification-message-content');
```

which will look at all previous siblings in the tree.

Comment: I think the problem is I am using a loop here. So same class appear 3 times. Thats why none of the answers are working for me. I think we have to find closest class name notification-message-content